# HDFS and redundancy

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm planning a data processing pipeline. My scenario is this:

- A user uploads data to a server
- This data should be distributed to one (and only one) node in my cluster. There is no distributed computing, just picking a node which has currently the least to do
- The data processing pipeline gets data from some kind of distributed job engine. Though here is (finally) my question: many job engines rely on HDFS to work on the data. But since this data is processed on one node only, I'd rather like to avoid to distribute it. But my understanding is that HDFS keeps the data redundant - though I could not find any info if this means whether all data on HDFS is available on all nodes, or the data is mostly on the node where it is processed (locality).

It would be a concern to me due to IO reasons for my usage scenario if data on HDFS would completely redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with Hadoop (Map Reduce + HDFS) to solve your problem.

1. You can tell HDFS to store specific number of copies as you want. See below **dfs.replication** property. Set this value to 1 if you want only one copy.

conf/hdfs-site.xml - On master and all slave machines

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>
```

Not necessary that HDFS copy data on each and every node. More [info](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Data+Replication).

2. Hadoop is work on principle that '**Move code to Data**'. Since moving code (mostly in MB's) demands very less network bandwidth than moving data in GB's or TB's, you no need to worry about data locality or network bandwidth. Hadoop take cares of it.